# FLOSS tools for facial recognition?

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, photography, face-recognition

There seem [to be good GUI tools](http://www.digikam.org/) to enable facial recognition with FLOSS, they all fall short of my requirements. And while there seem to be a lot of research projects with open code, they seem to be lacking in the "usable in real life" department.

It seems as if there should be something to scratch that itch, but I couldn't find it.

Thus, my wishlist for facial recognition software

- **MUST NOT send any data to any third parties!**
- Must run on Linux
- GUI and CLI are both fine as long as the rest of the specs are met, but good CLI-integration would be a huge plus
- Should offer batch-verification of detected faces [like so](http://www.digikam.org/node/696)
- Must not rely on duplicating files in its own data structure/DB/directory; symlinks are fine
- Should cope with source files disappearing
- Should be able to list/diff files which are new or not yet tagged
- Must not require being able to write to any picture files
- Must be able to store data outside of the original pictures
- Should not modify the source directories without being told to; temp files, face DB, and similar should all be located in a place I decide upon
- Should offer batch-processing
- Must be able to trigger a command or script for all verified identifications i.e. the ones I manually set to matching the person; alternatively, at least be able to export data in a way I can build scripts upon
- Should be able to cope with faces changing over time, people growing older, getting a beard, etc
- Should be FLOSS if at all possible
- I consider tags to be permanent, the DB for the program should ideally be ephemeral but I am aware that this may not be possible
- If the DB needs to be retained, it should ideally be in a merge-friendly text format not binary but that may be asking too much.

---

This is a verbatim copy<sup>1</sup> of http://richardhartmann.de/blog/posts/2014/03/03-Facial_recognition/ - while I didn't get any actual replies to my question, I have been pointed here as the most likely place for finding the answers I need.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, I lie. I need at least 10 magic brownie points to post more than two links at once.

Comment: [OpenCV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV), perhaps?

Comment: related http://superuser.com/questions/420885/is-there-a-face-recognition-command-line-tool

Answer (score 4):

### [Luxand](http://luxand.com/)

Multiple products but [the SDK is almost certainly what you want.](http://luxand.com/facesdk/) Runs on multiple platforms, including Linux. The list of features is even longer than your wishlist.

You wrote, however, "Should be FLOSS if at all possible." The product(s) that meet your requirements are not gratis. Furthermore, I could not find anything that indicated it was open source.

I am not associated with the product or company in any way.